# Electron-builder: EACCES: permission denied

Tags: node.js, macos, electron, electron-builder

I have tried to package my electron app on mac using electron-builder. There are no errors while doing so, however, once I try to open the app I get the following error:

> A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
>
> Uncaught Exception:
>
> Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir

I have not found any similar errors related to electron-builder and it also works just fine for windows. I have also tried 'sudo'.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

First, try uninstalling electron with the npm uninstall command.

```
sudo npm uninstall -g electron
```

Then reinstall electron with

```
sudo npm install -g electron --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

If that doesn't work, you can do the same with node.

```
sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm
```

Comment: this answer is not helpful because the OP mentions the behavior happening after the package is built, something I have also seen. Also, you should never (perhaps avoid at all costs) install npm packages using `sudo`

Answer (score 0):

I got mine working by including the node_modules's bin folders. I use to have

```
"!**/node_modules/.bin"
```

in the *files* parameter in the *build* param in **package.json.**

I removed this so now it includes the bin of each of the node modules.

I also include electron-updater and all of it's dependencies in the files parameter.